# Use different default applications to open .txt and .ply files

Tags: 20.04, default, text-editor, file-format

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. As is known, `.txt` suffix is for plain text files, and `.ply` is for polygon meshes. However, I find that for some weird reason, the default application to open `.txt` and `.ply` are always the same on ubuntu. Whenever I set meshlab as the default app for `.ply` files, the systems defaults to opening `.txt` with meshlab as well; and if I change the default app for `.txt` to text editor, the systems opens `.ply` files by text editor as well. This is absurd...can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that if you run a `mimetype` command on your `.ply` file, you'll obtain that it's a `text/plain` type. So, when you choose your default software for your file, you, in fact, choose for that mimetype.

These files are considered as plain text files.

According to [that thread](https://superuser.com/questions/459628/how-to-configure-linux-to-open-files-by-extension),

1. Create a file anywhere (let's go for `$HOME/ply-mime.xml`)
2. Copy paste that in it

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>  
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>  
    <mime-type type="application/extension-ply">  
        <comment>.ply file</comment>  
        <glob pattern="*.ply"/>  
    </mime-type>  
</mime-info>
```

3. Run in your terminal `xdg-mime install ply-mime.xml`. Now, you can do your "Select Default software for". It might need you restart your computer. I'm not sure.
4. You can delete `$HOME/ply-mime.xml`

Comment: Thanks! It worked. No need to restart in my case.